# How to add View dynamically from right side in Android?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I need to layout the views from the RIGHT side in a Fragment in Android, however, android did not layout the sub views as what I thought.
   I tried to add a TableLayout and an ImageView to a LINEARLAYOUT, the width of the ImageView was fixed and the width of TableLayout is dynamic. Furthermore, the ImageView need to be located on the right side.
   Part of the source code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(c);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    l.setLayoutParams(params);
    // l.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);



    PankouAttachmentView pav = new PankouAttachmentView(c, null);
    pav.setLayoutParams(params);
    l.addView(pav);

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(c);
    iv.setClickable(true);
    iv.setFocusable(true);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.testarrow);
    iv.setMaxWidth(BUTTON_WIDTH);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(BUTTON_WIDTH,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    l.addView(iv);

    return l;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.THX :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If someone gives you a helpful answer, please vote it up and/or accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question but have you tried using a relative layout? Relative layout lets you accomplish much easier than a linear layout. See the [android hello views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) tutorial.